# how can I change PRAGMA settings in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite

I need to change the pragma options to this.
How should I do it?
Where do i need to use this command? And how do i use it?

> PRAGMA default_synchronous = OFF;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PRAGMA](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html) is an [SQL command](http://www.sqlite.org/lang.html).
Just execute it like you would do with any other command, such as INSERT.

(Please note that SQLite simply ignores unknown PRAGMAs; the statement you've shown will have no effect.)